# a good tool for drawing figures and diagrams for thesis and research papers

Tags: diagrams

I’m looking a good tool for drawing figures and diagrams for thesis and research papers.

According to my findings, it seems like [inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) is a good tool for that purpose. Do you have some better ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- It depends on what sort of diagrams you need, but [Dia](http://dia-installer.de/) makes it easy to create various types of flowcharts, graphs, maps, etc.; is available for Windows, Mac, and Linux; and is free.

  [image]
  [image]

---

- If you have Microsoft Office, then [Visio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visio) is the perennial tool for this task.

  [image]
  [image]

Comment: +1 for quick reply. Most of my diagrams are related to Artificial Intelligence.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use Dia Diagram Editor it is a free software and you can download it from the link below.

http://dia-installer.de/

Answer (score 1):

Within academia Latex is a very popular authoring tool for documents. A stackexchange site for Latex users is [Tex - Stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Within Latex a popular tool for making figures is **Tikz**. A site showing a wide range of Tikz figure is http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/.

One of the examples from the site is shown below: (Source: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/parameterized-plots/)

[image: Figure A]